# Is there a term for groupBy that returns multiple groups?

Tags: scala, haskell, group-by, functional-programming

Type signature of `groupBy` is (in scala language, but really language-agnostic):

```
def groupBy[K](f: A => K): Map[K, Seq[A]]
```

I implemented a `groupBy` that returns multiple `K`, so that each `A` can be put into multiple groups at the same time. Something like this:

```
def multiGroupBy[K](f: A => Seq[K]): Map[K, Seq[A]]
```

I do something like:

```
case class Animal(name: String, traits: Seq[String])

List(
  Animal("cat", Seq("nocturnal", "feline")),
  Animal("dog", Seq("canine")),
  Animal("wolf", Seq("nocturnal", "canine"))
).multiGroupBy(animal => animal.traits)

// Map(nocturnal -> List(cat, wolf), feline -> List(cat), canine -> List(dog, wolf))
```

Name `multiGroupBy` works but I'm wondering if there is already a term (perhaps in haskell world?) for operation like above.

Comment: Does your project have a functional programming library dependency such as `Scalaz` or `cats`? If not, do you mind adding one? Because this can be solved with a `Monoid` and `foldMap`.

Comment: @MustafaSimav Yes, my project depends on `Scalaz`!

Comment: Shouldn't `multiGroupBy` return a `Map[K, Seq[A]]` and not `Map[K, A]`?

Comment: @TzachZohar Thanks. Corrected. Actually `groupBy` had to return `Map[K, Seq[A]]` as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Scalaz` dependency, you can do it with a `foldMap`.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class Animal(name: String, traits: Seq[String])

val animals = List(
  Animal("cat", Seq("nocturnal", "feline")),
  Animal("dog", Seq("canine")),
  Animal("wolf", Seq("nocturnal", "canine"))
)

val r1 = animals.foldMap(a => a.traits.map(t => t -> List(a)).toMap)
println(r1)
// Map(nocturnal -> List(Animal(cat,List(nocturnal, feline)), Animal(wolf,List(nocturnal, canine))), feline -> List(Animal(cat,List(nocturnal, feline))), canine -> List(Animal(dog,List(canine)), Animal(wolf,List(nocturnal, canine))))

val r2 = animals.foldMap(a => a.traits.map(t => t -> List(a.name)).toMap)
println(r2)
// Map(nocturnal -> List(cat, wolf), feline -> List(cat), canine -> List(dog, wolf))
```

What we did here is that we created a `Map[String, List[Animal]]` for each animal in animals list and let `Monoid[Map[String, List[Animal]]]` to merge each maps.

For example `Animal("cat", Seq("nocturnal", "feline"))` turned into `Map("nocturnal" -> List(Animal("cat", Seq("nocturnal", "feline"))), "feline" -> List(Animal("cat", Seq("nocturnal", "feline"))))`.

For furhter reading about monoid: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monoid.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I wanted to know was not the implementation of such operation (I implemented it already using similar implementation as scala's `groupBy`), but rather there is already a method for such operation. I'm pretty sure there isn't an equivalent in scala std but I was curious if there is a common terminology for it in general functional programming community.

Comment: So that I can name my new method better than `multiGroupBy` ;)